# Using Map with Typescript on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am a bit confused with how I would use Map on a nodejs project.

To use Map I have to set the compile target to ES6. If I do that however the js that is output uses ES6 imports which node complains about.

How do I turn on some ES6 features (like Map) but still use require rather than import?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please include your tsconfig.json? Or show the command you are using to compile if you aren't using one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `lib` property in your `tsconfig.json` file to enable ES6 features and set the `target` property to `es5` to control the emitted JS code:

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
        "es6"
    ]
}
```